# VBA - Reference Label in PowerPoint Presentation with UserForm

Tags: vba, label, activex, powerpoint, userform

I am attempting to use a VBA UserForm to edit an ActiveX label in a PowerPoint Presentation (which will serve as a textbox).  I can't determine how to reference the label, however, and could use some direction.  I have tried variations of 
`Presentations("Combined Staff Agenda Template").Slides(0).Shapes("Date_Label").Value = LabelDate`, 
but I still receive an error.  The ActiveX label is on the first slide of the "Combined Staff Agenda Template" presentation, and is named "Date_Label".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Presentations("Combined Staff Agenda Template").Slides(0) _
                     .Shapes("Date_Label").OLEFormat.Object.Caption = LabelDate
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, that is it!  Would any ActiveX control be an `OLEFormat.Object`?

Comment: Tim, I have one more issue I'm trying to resolve, and I figured I would ask here.  My script is opening various Presentations and copying the slides into a Master.  If one of the source Presentations is open by another user, however, I receive an 80004005 error on this line: `Set PPT = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(File.Path, ReadOnly:=msoTrue, WithWindow:=msoFalse)`.  Any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: Are you automating PPT from another application? I notice you have `PPTApp` in your problem code.  And what is `File` in that line?

Comment: Tim, I have posted my script in another question (rather than adding another comment).  It can be found here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836017/vba-automated-powerpoint-wont-open-pptx-file-that-is-being-used-by-another-u).  Thank you for your help!