# Change Textbox written, properties (PowerPoint VBA)

Tags: vba, textbox, powerpoint

I tryed the following code, to change the size of the font of the TextBox that is written the name in the TextBox 'txtboxselection'. For example if the text of the TextBox 'txtboxselection' is 'TextBox1' then it should change the font size of the TextBox1.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim e_sel As TextBox
Set e_sel = txtboxselection.Text
e_sel.Font.Size = 11
End Sub
```

But, unfortunately it doesn't work ('Compile Error: Type mismatch'). So is there any way to tell the program that I want to change the font size of the TextBox written in the "txtboxselection' TextBox, because mine didn't work.

Comment: Not sure, Try: `Set e_sel = TextBox(txtboxselection.Text)`

Comment: Didn't work. In bold is the problem: Set e_sel = **TextBox** (txtboxselection.Text) | **EDIT**: Sub or function doesn't exist

Comment: `Me.Controls(txtboxselection.Text).Font.Size = 11`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the text font to change when something happens in the userform? Otherwise, you could always just change the size of the font in the properties window the userform.

Comment: Well, I don't know if you know but I'm in PowerPoint using VBA.

Comment: How would we know that?  Maybe you can add a few more details to your question: that will help people give you useful suggestions.

Comment: I thought that VBA is only for Office Apps, and VB.NET is for Visual Studio. Sorry

Comment: VBA is hosted in well over 200 host applications, *including* MS Office.

Comment: Oh ok. can you still help me with the problem?

Comment: Uh, sure, but all I'll do is turn [Tim's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45381587/change-textbox-written-properties-powerpoint-vba#comment77724927_45381587) into an answer - because that's your answer. Or is that `TextBox` control an ActiveX control on a PowerPoint slide?

Comment: Do you mean the TextBox in code? If yes, then it's not.

Comment: Then what is it? Please [edit] your question to clarify, it's unanswerable until we know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you talking about my code or Tim's code? Beacuse in my code the "TextBox" means the type of object, I think.

Comment: Very very very close to being a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22821389/1188513) IMO.

Comment: I got the answer by Mat's Mug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your textbox is an ActiveX control on a PowerPoint slide, you need to query the `Shapes` collection to get to the control, and retrieve its `OLEFormat.Object` to get a `TextBox` object:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim box1 As TextBox
Set box1 = Me.Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object
MsgBox box1.Font.Size
End Sub
```

Once you have your `TextBox` object reference, you can do anything you want with it. So in your case:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
Dim e_sel As TextBox
Set e_sel = Me.Shapes(txtboxselection.Text).OLEFormat.Object
e_sel.Font.Size = 11
End Sub
```